# Failed to invoke private data.coroutine.Result() with no args

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines, dagger-hilt

I am building an app and need to access the backend using REST Api. So I have decided to use Retrofit, mvvm, coroutine and dagger-hilt.

When I am placing the call to the REST Api, I can see the `GET` and also the response back which is exactly what I was expected. Unfortunately, I got an exception in the viewModel when calling it.

ViewModel.kt

```
fun getOauthConfig(email: String) {
        val domain = extractDomainFromEmail(email)
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                _uiState.value = SignInUiState.Loading
                when (val response = repository.getOauthConfig(
                    generateToken(),
                    BuildConfig.SUBSCRIPTION_KEY,
                    domain
                )) {
                    is Result.Success<*> -> {
                        Log.d("TAG", "Json response: " + response.data)
                        _uiState.value = SignInUiState.Success
                    }
                    is Result.Error -> {
                        _uiState.value = SignInUiState.Error(response.exception)
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                _uiState.value = SignInUiState.Error(e)
            }
        }
    }
```

the `ViewModel` call the `repository` as define below:

```
class Repository @Inject constructor(
    private val apiHelper: ApiHelperInterface
) {
    suspend fun getOauthConfig(token: String, key: String, domain: String) = apiHelper.getOauthConfig(token, key, domain)
}
```

then the `apiHelper`

```
class ApiHelper @Inject constructor(
    private val api: ApiServices
): ApiHelperInterface {
    override suspend fun getOauthConfig(token: String,
                                        key: String,
                                        domain: String): Result<OauthConfigResponse> = api.getOauthConfig(token, key, domain)
}
```

and called finally the api side as below:

```
interface ApiServices {
    @GET("/multiplexer-service-clone/oauth-config")
    suspend fun getOauthConfig(@Header("Authorization") token: String,
                               @Header("Key") key: String,
                               @Query("domain") domain: String,): Result<OauthConfigResponse>
}
```

I have defined `Result` to be used by the co-routine and it's define as below:

```
sealed class Result<out T : Any> {
    data class Success<out T : Any>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()
}
```

The REST API response `OauthConfigResponse` is defined as below:

```
data class OauthConfigResponse(
    var clientId: String,
    var discoveryUri: String,
    var redirectUri: String,
    var scope: String
)
```

When I am placing the call from the ViewModel, the co-routine seems generating an exception which is catch by the `try{} catch` from the viewModel itself. Below is the error

```
Failed to invoke private com.xxx.xxx.data.coroutine.Result() with no args
```

Any idea why the app trigger an exception ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `Result` class as a response of `ApiServices. getOauthConfig()` request. I haven't seen anywhere in the docs that `Result` class can be used as a response, it is a class from Kotlin std library, not retrofit library. Instead use `retrofit2.Response` class:

```
interface ApiServices {
    @GET("/multiplexer-service-clone/oauth-config")
    suspend fun getOauthConfig(
        @Header("Authorization") token: String,
        @Header("Key") key: String,
        @Query("domain") domain: String,
    ): Response<OauthConfigResponse>
}
```

And in `ApiHelper` class you can map the `Response` object to `Result` object:

```
class ApiHelper @Inject constructor(
    private val api: ApiServices
) {
    suspend fun getOauthConfig(
        token: String,
        key: String,
        domain: String
    ): Result<OauthConfigResponse> {
        val response: Response<OauthConfigResponse> = api. getOauthConfig(token, key, domain)
        return if (response.isSuccessful) {
            Result.success(response.body()!!)
        } else {
            Result.failure(HttpException(response))
        }
    }
}
```